# trying to download full HTML pages

Tags: python, html

I am tring to download few hundreds of HTML pages in order to parse them and calculate some measures.
I tried it with linux `WGET`, and with a loop of the following code in python:

```
url = "https://www.camoni.co.il/411788/168022"
html = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
```

but the html file I got doen't contain all the content I see in the browser in the same page. for example text I see on the screen is not found in the HTML file. only when I right click the page in the browser and "Save As" i get the full page.
the problem - I need a big anount of pages and can not do it by hand.

URL example - https://www.camoni.co.il/411788/168022 - thelast number changes

thank you

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't contain all the content I see in the browser"? What is "content"?

Comment: pictures and text

Comment: You might want to use selenium and a headless browser to click on save as.

Comment: selenium is a browser? because my problem is that I need a way to do it a few hundred times and nit ine time in a browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because that site is not static. It uses JavaScript (in this example jQuery lib) to fetch additional data from server and paste on page.

So instead of trying to GET raw HTML you should inspect requests in developer tools. There's a POST request on https://www.camoni.co.il/ajax/tabberChangeTab with such data:

```
tab_name=tab_about
memberAlias=ד-ר-דינה-ראלט-PhD
currentURL=/411788/ד-ר-דינה-ראלט-PhD
```

And the result is HTML that pasted on page after.

So instead of trying to just download page you should inspect page and requests to get data or use headless browser such as Google Chrome to emulate 'Save As' button and save data.